# get set number of diffrent items in one query

Tags: solr, solr4

Hello in my solr index i have items that are in 3 sections (field section with string value)

I want in my search results to pick 10 items from each sections (i have over 1000 of each sections items). I need to display list with 30 items where is 10 items from each section. I could do this by 3 diffrent queries but I want to make 1 query. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no.

Most popular solutions are filter queries and having multiple values for a given field i.e. categories:c1,c2 but they do not ensure that you will get at least 10 from each section. With these implementations you would need a little front-end logic to go over the results and extract 10 from each category.

However, if you do find a solution where SOLR does that for you, please let me know as I'm curious to how it can be done.